# Neural Net MSE trough

Tags: neural-network, stocks, fann

I am trying to train a BackProp Neural Net with 21 inputs and 1 output.

The input data is S&P 500 stock data (indicators) and the output is if a buy should occur.

I have tried a number of neural net configurations but as the epochs progress the MSE gets larger after a decent as seen in the picture below.

[image]

Does this behavior denote something about my data or that something is wrong?

Comment: Is that the MSE on the training data or the test data?

Comment: It is on the training data.

Comment: Can you give more information about the neural net work you are training and could you shows an exact plot of the MSE?

Comment: I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855720/c-c-fann-error-barely-drops-and-then-goes-back-up-again